# How to put a textview behind a button?

Tags: android

I have this problem, that I want to elevate my "Menu" buttons but the elevation bugs and it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sG0Uu.png). I figured butting an empty TextView behind them and elevating it. Yet when I do this it gets in front of the buttons and visually covers them, yet the buttons are still functioning (it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zl7PO.png)). I made it to be created before the buttons, yet it still doesn't work. How to fix it?

Edit: activity.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".PortfolioActivity">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Background_for_buttons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#FF000000" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/portfolio_button"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
        android:layout_width="128dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:text="Portfolio" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/settings_button"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
        android:layout_width="128dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:text="Settings" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/home_button"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
        android:layout_width="128dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:text="Overview" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="226dp"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:elevation="20dp"
        android:text="ASDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_coin_button"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:text="ADD" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: show us your Activity's XML layout

Comment: @Dawit added in the question

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is wrong. Use the code below, I just used a horizontal LinearLayout inside a vertical LinearLayout for your menu, and removed your textView. WeightSum is used so that all your 3 buttons will have the same width and fill the screen width.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".PortfolioActivity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="3">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/home_button"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:text="Overview" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/portfolio_button"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:text="Portfolio" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/settings_button"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:text="Settings" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="226dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:elevation="20dp"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:text="ASDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/add_coin_button"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:text="ADD" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```